# Converting timezone in in Python (Django) adding a mysterious 30 minutes

Tags: python, django, date, datetime

I have a datetime object that is set to `2014-02-24 19:00:00+00:00` and I believe this is set as UTC by default (through the Django admin panel).

This time is actually Africa/Johannesburg, so I convert it like this:

```
local_timezone= pytz.timezone("Africa/Johannesburg")
local_time_start = self.start_time_unix.replace(tzinfo=local_timezone)
```

This will now output `2014-02-24 19:00:00+01:30`

Now I want to store this as the converted UTC timezone, so I do it like this:

```
utc_time = local_time_start.astimezone(utc)
```

For some reason, this outputs `2014-02-24 17:30:00+00:00`. The time is should output is `17:00:00` so where is the extra 30 mins coming from?

Basically I am trying to take the given input from the django admin panel as the local timezone of the models time_zone field, but store it as UTC.

Is there a better way I can approach this? The Django docs explain how to convert the users local timezone but I need to convert it based on the timezone in the models attributes.

Comment: Your timezone is incorrect, `+01:30` is not timezone for Johannesburg. The rest is just a consequence, result is 17:30, because 19:00 - 1:30 = 17:30.

Comment: @vartec: the timezone is perfectly correct, but only for historical dates. The Johannesburg timezone *at some point in time* was +01:30. The PyTZ timezone object reflects this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use `datetime.replace()` with `pytz` timezones. The `pytz` timezones contain historical timezone data (to allow for dates in the past to use the right offsets from UTC), but `datetime.replace()` cannot use the correct information in that case.

Use the `timezone.localize()` method instead:

```
local_timezone = pytz.timezone("Africa/Johannesburg")
local_time_start = local_timezone.localize(self.start_time_unix)
```

See the [`pytz` documentation](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/#localized-times-and-date-arithmetic).

Use this only on non-timezone-aware objects. For timezone aware `datetime` values, use [`datetime.astimezone()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.astimezone) to translate value from one timezone to another:

```
local_timezone = pytz.timezone("Africa/Johannesburg")
local_time_start = self.start_time_unix.astimezone(local_timezone)
```

If you have a `datetime` value that has the *wrong* timezone attached (it should represent the given time in a different timezone, not a different time in that timezone), remove the old timezone first using `.replace(tzinfo=None), then use`timezone.localize()`:

```
local_timezone = pytz.timezone("Africa/Johannesburg")
local_time_start = local_timezone.localize(self.start_time_unix.replace(tzinfo=None))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When I try this, I get a ValueError exception `Not naive datetime (tzinfo is already set)`. Do you know why this is?

Comment: In that case you are not attaching a timezone, you are translating between timezones. Use `datetime.datetime.astimezone()` for that (see updated answer).

Comment: Thanks Martijn. The problem is it already *thinks* it's a UTC time, so astimezone will convert 19:00:00 to 21:00:00 (because it's converting from UTC to Johannesburg). I want it to change it to 19:00:00 Johannesburg time.

Comment: Then remove the incorrect timezone first, then use `.localize()`; answer updated.